# Scala Pattern Matching Compiler Warning

Tags: scala

I caused a bug in my code that was tougher to find that I would have liked, and something that I'd ideally like to avoid in the future. I expected the Scala compiler would have warned me about my error (unless I'm missing something).

I've reduced it to the trivial case:

```
Vector.maybeGetVector match {
  case v:Vector => true
  case _ => false
}

case class Vector(x:Int, y:Int)

object Vector {
  def maybeGetVector : Option[Vector] = Some(new Vector(1,2))
}
```

The only reason I used `wildcard` instead of `None` for the fall through is that I only want to match on a subtype of the returned `Option`.

I was expecting a compiler warning, as it's easy to reason that the first case statement contains unreachable code. `Option[Vector]` can't be a subtype of `Vector`.

The strange part is that if I add the following case statement:

```
 case i:Int => false
```

It raises an error and tells me that `Option[Vector]` is required.

Is there a way to protect against programmer error in this way, outside of naming conventions. The only things that can ever match against an `Option` are `Some/None/null`. I feel I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I think this is worth opening an enhancement ticket. Scala 2.10 has a completely new pattern matching code. The old one not only did not catch this, but was full of bugs, and was very difficult to understand and fix, much less improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define your Vector class with a `final` modifier, you'll get the "pattern type is incompatible with expected type" error you're expecting.

To me that says that Scala thinks your Option[Vector] might somehow be an instance of a subtype of Vector.  (This seems impossible to me, but I think that's the reasoning at work.)  Making Vector final precludes that seemingly remote possibility.

So, if the first case statement should be unreachable, it's not because, as you said, Vector can't be a subtype of Option[Vector]; but rather because an Option[Vector] can't be an instance of a subtype of Vector.  Maybe that's what you meant :)

Comment: Yep, you're right on that last bit, had to read it out about 5 times to get it straight :)

Comment: Adding final gave the desired error. It's a bit strange, Option is a sealed abstract class, it's not like it's a mixable trait (which a subtype of Vector could mixin etc.).